# Why does calling filp_open in a soft interrupt handler result in a general protection fault?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to implement a custom soft interrupt handler which is different from the default 0x80 interrupt used to implement linux system calls.

I've installed the interrupt handler at 0x7F and issuing "int 0x7F" from userspace successfully runs my handler. Since I need to read a file, which is a strange thing but anyway, I need to invoke filp_open in the handler, which gave me a general protection fault in the kernel log:

```
[ 3853.779411] general protection fault: 0000 [#12] SMP 
[ 3853.779429] Modules linked in: callback_mod(OF) nls_utf8 isofs vesafb(F) vboxsf(OF) snd_intel8x0 snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device snd microcode vboxvideo(OF) joydev drm rfcomm bnep bluetooth parport_pc psmouse serio_raw ppdev soundcore snd_page_alloc i2c_piix4 mac_hid vboxguest(OF) lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid ahci libahci e1000 [last unloaded: callback_mod]
[ 3853.779449] CPU: 0 PID: 6349 Comm: test Tainted: GF     D    O 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu
[ 3853.779451] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[ 3853.779453] task: db0b4060 ti: dbcca000 task.ti: dbcca000
[ 3853.779454] EIP: 0060:[<c1176bc4>] EFLAGS: 00010082 CPU: 0
[ 3853.779488] EIP is at get_empty_filp+0x14/0x1d0
[ 3853.779489] EAX: ffffff9c EBX: ffffff9c ECX: dbccbf38 EDX: dbccbfc4
[ 3853.779490] ESI: 00000000 EDI: dbccbfc4 EBP: dbccbec8 ESP: dbccbea8
[ 3853.779492]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 0000 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
[ 3853.779496] CR0: 8005003b CR2: b7563f80 CR3: 1bdab000 CR4: 000006f0
[ 3853.779500] Stack:
[ 3853.779501]  dbda8b18 dbccbeec c1144c54 dbdbedd0 0000002d ffffff9c dbccbf38 dbccbfc4
[ 3853.779505]  dbccbf24 c1182678 c8b3dc40 b7563f80 00000000 dc05c660 00000000 dfbf0000
[ 3853.779508]  dbdbedd0 dbccbf28 c1145b5a dbda8b18 dbdbedd0 dbccbfc4 dbccbf18 00000000
[ 3853.779512] Call Trace:
[ 3853.779516]  [<c1144c54>] ? handle_pte_fault+0x94/0x2b0
[ 3853.779519]  [<c1182678>] path_openat+0x28/0x3f0
[ 3853.779521]  [<c1145b5a>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x1fa/0x2d0
[ 3853.779524]  [<c11834c5>] do_filp_open+0x35/0x80
[ 3853.779526]  [<c1176b3d>] ? ____fput+0xd/0x10
[ 3853.779529]  [<c1070d46>] ? task_work_run+0xb6/0xd0
[ 3853.779532]  [<c117463b>] file_open_name+0xeb/0x150
[ 3853.779534]  [<c11746ce>] filp_open+0x2e/0x30
[ 3853.779537]  [<e098703e>] my_intercept+0x2e/0x50 [callback_mod]
[ 3853.779538] Code: ee ff 8b 5d f4 8b 75 f8 8b 7d fc 89 ec 5d c3 90 8d b4 26 00 00 00 00 55 89 e5 57 56 53 83 ec 14 66 66 66 66 90 8b 35 08 a4 9e c1 <64> a1 d0 5f b5 c1 8b b8 00 03 00 00 a1 04 a4 9e c1 89 45 ec 89
[ 3853.779559] EIP: [<c1176bc4>] get_empty_filp+0x14/0x1d0 SS:ESP 0068:dbccbea8
[ 3853.779563] ---[ end trace c6286c432f82c27f ]---
```

Here's my handler:

```
asmlinkage void isr0x0E( void );
asm("   .text                       ");
asm("   .type   isr0x0E, @function          ");
asm("isr0x0E:                       ");
asm("   call    my_intercept              ");
asm("   iret                       ");
```

And this is the function called above:

```
static void my_intercept(void)                                              
{
    char* f = "/tmp/test.txt";
    struct file* fs = file_open(f, O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0644);
    file_close(fs);
}
```

In the above, file_open and file_close calls filp_open and filp_close respectively.

Also, if I call printk in my_intercept, it gives me a GPF, too.

Am I supposed to use these functions in a interrupt handler? Do I miss anything?

Comment: `printk()` on interrupt handler ?!? you need to think twice...

Comment: @rakib I know it's strange, in my case it does not matter if it slows down the system, I just wanna know if there is any constraint placed by the kernel that prevents this.

Comment: well what I know is - if you call `printk()` that will ended up being calling schedule() which indicates you are leaving the interrupt handling context and that is something which is highly unlikely and avoided. If you really what something like that, you can try using ftrace's printk() support, see the docs.

Comment: @rakib I see. How about filp_open?

Comment: as you've faced, it's too uncertain, perhaps you should consider doing it on top half or on some other context.

Comment: Yeah - in an interrupt-handler, there is very litle you can do, and that small set certainly doesn't include file management.

Comment: @MartinJames Is there any document about what is in this small set?